# Python gives different result when running in Local PC and Windows Server

Tags: python, winapi, windows-server-2016, xlwings

I'm running the same python scripts in my PC and Windows server. Pointing in the same Project Interpreter (`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe`) plus using the same version and package too. My code run perfect in Local PC but produce different result in server. Here is the code:

```
import win32com.client as xl
import xlwings.constants

bookName = r'C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\Python_Projects\test_case.xlsx'
# in server the path is 'D:\Programmer\Python\test_case.xlsx'

sf = xl.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
scBk = sf.Workbooks.Open(bookName)
#to find sheet "T16_T"
#sht= scBk.Worksheets[1] -->old code
#edit with this new code
for list_sht in scBk.Sheets:
   sht= scBk.Worksheets[list_sht.Name]; break
sf.Visible = True

rngtofind= sht.Cells.Find(What='Total', LookAt=xlwings.constants.LookAt.xlWhole, LookIn=xlwings.constants.FindLookIn.xlFormulas, MatchCase = False)
If rngtofind is not None:
   print(rngtofind.Address)

scBk.Close()
sf.Quit()
```

The different result that I encountered:

1. Local PC :

   - `sht= scBk.Worksheets[1]` --> `"T16_T"`
   - `rngtofind.Address` --> `$C$6`, `Total`
2. Windows server, after amend the code:

   - `sht= scBk.Worksheets[1]` --> `"T16_T"`
   - `rngtofind.Address` --> `$B$3`, `(TOTAL)`

Is there any way to fix this issue? FYI, I want the same code is applied and don't want to maintain 2 different version of code at the same time.

Additional info:

- Python 3.6
- Pycharm
- Windows 7-64bit
- Windows Server 2016-64bit
  [image: Sample case "T16_T"][image: Sample case "T16_M"]

Edit:
To avoid using the index in worksheet as per IInspectable mention, came out with another solution in searching. Please refer the code.

Comment: Why are you passing a numeric index instead of the (presumably) known name to reference a worksheet? It seems the [object model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.sheets.item?view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_Sheets_Item_System_Object_) supports both.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for your quick response. FYI, the excel file is from vendor and it was so unstable layout and pattern (sometimes will change the name of the sheet and will adding some space). The only one that I know is we will always refer the first sheet which is why I'm using the index. That's why its driving me crazy as it supposedly supports both

Comment: @IInspectable I think the only way that I can do is to get the first sheet by using `for` loop which is not really smart but it's work. Unfortunately, I still hit the same issue for `rngtofind.Address` which is pointed to `(TOTAL)` instead of `Total`. Again, the same question. What is the cause and how to fix this. T_T

Comment: `Worksheets` returns an `IEnumerable` interface. I don't know, how that is projected into Python, but surely there should be an implementation that allows you to reference the first item, without using the verbose C-like syntax (`.GetEnumerator().MoveNext().Current()`). Your getting different results for `rgntofind` is just a corollary of selecting different worksheets, and using inappropriate settings for the `Find` invocation. At a guess, all of this is caused by an (application) setting, that changes, whether arrays are 0-based or 1-based, plus locale settings, changing how `Find` operates.

Comment: After I amend my code. Its work and point to exactly the sheetname that I want T16_T same in Windows server. Now, the result for rngtofind is point to different address. I'm sure using the appropriate settings as xlwings is same as VBA settings for find range cause i'm using VBA excel for quite long time but not sure how its work in python. If you said caused by application settings and etc. May I know how to change it?